Minipage misaligned with right margin
I'm new to LaTeX and trying to figure out minipage environments. I have an environment set up to provide me with two columns:
% Environments
\newenvironment{twocolumns}[2]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth} % Main text column
    #1
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth} % Date column
    \hfill \textcolor{gray}{#2}
    \end{minipage}
}


The right column is ever so slightly misalgined with the right margin. The date at the bottom of this image is currently aligned using \hfill.
I can fix this by instead of using \hfill between the two minipage columns, by adding either a space of 0.1\textwidth, or making sure each column adds up to 1\textwidth. However, this produces an overfill and underfill warning everytime I end my twocolumns environment.
I have also added \setlength{\parindent}{0cm} to remove any indents but this has not changed the issue.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

You are missing % at the end of lines, see Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?

Also the environment lacks the closing part. Are you sure that a \newcommand wouldn't be better suited?

Ah brilliant, the % at the end of lines I was unaware about. I'll have a look at using \newcommand as well. Thank you.
